# search table view based on date picker

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, uidatepicker

i am trying to search my table view based on date using date picker but for some reason the table doesnt not update.

the goal is to display the cells that only match the date choose from date picker.
Here is my table view code :

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        let client = clinetarr[indexPath.row]

        var output: String = ""
        var resp: String = ""
        var datee: String = ""
        var index: String = ""

cell.message.numberOfLines=0

        if let i = client["index"] as? String {
            index = "\(i) "  //using space as separator

        }
        if let date = client["date"] as? String {
            datee = "\(date) "  //using space as separator


        }


        if let response = client["response"] as? String {
            resp = "\(response) "

        }

        if let message = client["message"] as? String {
            output = message
        }
        cell.indextnumber.text = index
        cell.response.text = resp
        cell.date.text = datee
        cell.message.text = output


        return cell
    }
```

here is my date picker code & done buttom fuunc

```
 func createDatePicker() {


        let toolbar = UIToolbar()
        toolbar.sizeToFit()


        let done = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(donebuttom))
        toolbar.setItems([done], animated: false)

        dateField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
        dateField.inputView = picker


        picker.datePickerMode = .date
    }

    @objc func donebuttom() -> UITableViewCell{

        var output: String = ""
        var resp: String = ""
        var datee: String = ""
        var index: String = ""

        // format date
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

        let dateString = formatter.string(from: picker.date)
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        let client = clinetarr[indexPath.row]
        dateField.text = "\(dateString)"


        if let date = client["date"] as? String {

            let dateee = "\(date) "

             let last = dateee.prefix(10)
            if last == dateString{
                if let i = client["index"] as? String {
                    index = "\(i) "

                }
                if let date = client["date"] as? String {
                    datee = "\(date) "  //using space as separator


                }


                if let response = client["response"] as? String {
                    resp = "\(response) "

                }

                if let message = client["message"] as? String {
                    output = message
                }
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
            else{
                resp=""
                 tableView.reloadData()
            }

        }

        cell.indextnumber.text = index
        cell.response.text = resp
        cell.date.text = datee
        cell.message.text = output

        tableView.reloadData()
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return cell
    }
```

for some reason the table doesn't not update
Thanks in advance

Thanks for every one answer i solve it.
Especial thanks for Duncan C , answer was simple but i guess my Brain was fried .

Comment: In your function donebuttom() you should rather manipulate your UITableViewDataSource (Array "clientarr") than returning a UITableViewCell.

Comment: Can you explain more or give an example?

Comment: Every time you call tableView.reloadData() the method cellForRow:at: is called. It doesn't matter that you are returning a UITableViewCell from doneButtom() (you are not even using this UITableViewCell).
You will need either another dataSource-Array like "filteredClientArr" + some logic in cellForRow:at: to use the correct array dependend on if you need a filtered list or not. Or you need to manipulate your "clientarr" to sort out the entries you do not need.

Comment: i did the new array but iam new for tableview. how i can make the tableview update with the new array once donebuttom clicked?

Answer (score 0):

You don't search a table view. A table view has a data source, which provides cells from your model.

If you want to filter your table view you need to create a new array with the subset of items you want to display, write your data source methods so they know to  use the filtered list of items, and then call reloadData() on the table view. The table view will take care of figuring out how many sections and rows there are and displaying the cells for your filtered data.

Comment: Ok so i made a new method and stored the new array in it how i will update the tableview once done botton clicked?

Comment: Create an instance variable `useFilteredArray`
. Set it to true when you want to only show a subset of the data. In your data source methods, check the flag to decide what array to use for the number of rows, and to build cells in `cellForRowAt()`.

Comment: can you write in code if you dont mind my brain is stuck

Comment: No, I don't have time to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer :

```
@objc func donebuttom() {

    // format date
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

     dateString = formatter.string(from: picker.date)

    dateField.text = "\(dateString)"
    let x =  dateString.count
     print ("here is x \(x)")

    doneclick = true
    tableView.reloadData()
    self.view.endEditing(true)

}
```

Here is my table View

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
       client = clinetarr[indexPath.row]


cell.message.numberOfLines=0
        if doneclick == true{
            if let date = client["date"] as? String {

                let dateee = "\(date)"
                let last = dateee.prefix(10)
                let y = last.count

                if last == dateString{

                    if let i = client["index"] as? String {
                        index = "\(i) "  //using space as separator

                    }
                    if let date = client["date"] as? String {
                        datee = "\(date) "  //using space as separator

                    }

                    if let response = client["response"] as? String {
                        //            resp = "\(response) "
                        let x = "\(response) "
                        print ("\(x) ")
                        if x.contains("1"){
                            resp = "Present"
                        }
                        else if x.contains("2"){
                            resp = "Absent"
                        }

                        else if x.contains("3"){
                            resp = "Tardy"
                        }

                    }

                    if let message = client["message"] as? String {
                        output = message
                    }
                }else{
                    index = ""
                    datee = ""
                    resp = ""
                    output = ""
                }
            }

        }else{
        if let i = client["index"] as? String {
            index = "\(i) "  //using space as separator

        }

        if let date = client["date"] as? String {

            datee = "\(date) "  //using space as separator


        }


        if let response = client["response"] as? String {
//            resp = "\(response) "
            let x = "\(response) "
            print ("\(x) ")
            if x.contains("1"){
                resp = "Present"
            }
            else if x.contains("2"){
                resp = "Absent"
            }

            else if x.contains("3"){
                resp = "Tardy"
            }

        }

        if let message = client["message"] as? String {
            output = message
        }
        }
        cell.indextnumber.text = index
        cell.response.text = resp
        cell.date.text = datee
        cell.message.text = output


        return cell
    }
```